# C++ not executing on M1 Mac VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

Code able to compile, but not executing, i.e. output not showing in debug window, breakpoints are not hit. Same configuration was working on non M1 Mac

Task.json:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
  {
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "clang++ build active file",
    "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
    "args": [
      "-std=c++17",
      "-stdlib=libc++",
      "-g",
      "${file}",
      "-o",
      "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    ],
    "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    }
  }
]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
    }
]
}
```

cp_properties.json

```
{
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Mac",
    "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
    "defines": [],
    "macFrameworkPath": [
      "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
    ],
    "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
    "cStandard": "c11",
    "cppStandard": "c++17",
    "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
  }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g 
/Users/gyan/workplace/vscode/test/test.cpp -o /Users/gyan/workplace/vscode/test/test
Build finished successfully.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   string s = "my     name  is      Gyan p\n";
   istringstream iss(s);

   string word;
   cout<<"s";

   while(iss >> word){
       cout<<word<<" ";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Not getting any idea of the issue

Comment: What happens if you place a breakpoint at the start of `main`.  Perhaps your program is crashing.  Anyway, please share `test.cpp` with us, we're just guessing here.

Comment: added test.cpp.
If in vscode terminal, I run ./test, I get the output correctly, just not working with Run->Start Debuggung

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using following config changes in `launch.json`:

```
"-arch", "x86_64",


"targetArchitecture": "x86_64",
"osx": {
                "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            }
```